# Is Orc or Imperial better for a one-handed heavy armor warrior?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I'm starting a new character, a one-handed heavy armored warrior with shield (or maybe a spell). Imperials get a gold bonus, while an orc's starting stats fit the play style. The Imperial may only gain a few septims at a time, but by the end of the game it could be substantial.

Which race is a better choice?

Comment: This question is pretty much just asking for opinions. But I think if you rephrased it as "Which race is better suited for my intended playstyle?" I think it be on-topic

Comment: idk if this has been edited and it's different now than when @twobugs posted, but it looks fine as it is.  The OP asks in the title which race is better for a warrior style, and the races do have different starting stats and powers, so the different races will make a difference (especially early game).  This looks like a fine question to me as is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [Imperial bonus](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Imperial_Luck#Imperial_Luck) isn't really worth it:

> 100% chance of 2-10 extra gold in all chests that normally contain gold, as well as to the corpses of various gold-dropping enemies, such as bandits, dragons, draugr, Falmer, Forsworn, giants, and rieklings

Honestly, 2-10 gold per loot is pretty low, especially in the mid-to-late game where weapons and armor you loot are worth way more.

If you're going all-out as a fighter, you'll get a lot more use out of the Orc bonuses.

Comment: Orc would be better than Imperial, but Redguard is even better. Their ability regenerates stamina quickly, allowing you to fully use your shield and your power strikes.

Answer (score -1):

I liked to use an Argonian warrior, because when fighting multiple enemies at close range it is almost impossible to block. That's when the Histskin ability comes in handy, allowing you to tank and regen through enemy hits with; once you've used the ability, however, keep in mind that it will take 24 hours to be able to use it again.

Comment: It's not as good as the orcs' Beserker Rage

Answer (score -1):

Doesn't matter, that is the cool thing about skyrim it doesn't matter which character you use at all. Just choose what u feel comftable with I mean they all have different abilities. U can use wood elf heavy armour warrior if you wanted to but if ur dead set on it just use Orc. Beserk ability is useful but my opinion is that orcs are just plain ugly.